# Adjusting splines for covariates

Tags: splines

I consider fitting cubic splines in R.

**Question**: How can I include covariates in my spline model?

---

The first few lines of my toy dataset are as follows

```
> library(ISLR)  # contains "Wage" dataset
> head(Wage)
       year age           maritl     race       education
231655 2006  18 1. Never Married 1. White    1. < HS Grad
86582  2004  24 1. Never Married 1. White 4. College Grad
161300 2003  45       2. Married 1. White 3. Some College
155159 2003  43       2. Married 3. Asian 4. College Grad
11443  2005  50      4. Divorced 1. White      2. HS Grad
376662 2008  54       2. Married 1. White 4. College Grad
                   region       jobclass         health health_ins
231655 2. Middle Atlantic  1. Industrial      1. <=Good      2. No
86582  2. Middle Atlantic 2. Information 2. >=Very Good      2. No
161300 2. Middle Atlantic  1. Industrial      1. <=Good     1. Yes
155159 2. Middle Atlantic 2. Information 2. >=Very Good     1. Yes
11443  2. Middle Atlantic 2. Information      1. <=Good     1. Yes
376662 2. Middle Atlantic 2. Information 2. >=Very Good     1. Yes
        logwage      wage
231655 4.318063  75.04315
86582  4.255273  70.47602
161300 4.875061 130.98218
155159 5.041393 154.68529
11443  4.318063  75.04315
376662 4.845098 127.11574
```

I use the `splines` library to fit `wage` against `age`:

```
# Fit cubic spline
fit <- lm(wage ~ bs(age, knots = c(25, 40, 60)), data = Wage)

# Visualize fit
age_grid <- 20:80
lines(age_grid, predict(fit, newdata = list(age = age_grid)),
       col="darkgreen", lwd = 3)
```

[image]

**Question**: How can I obtain two fits depending on the health status (variable `health`), with the assumption of homogeneous residual variance?

Comment: Include `health` in the formula?

Comment: Do you want a *different* smooth function for each level of `health` or just want a purely additive model? In general, look at the class of models called generalized additive models - recent developments such as those included in the *mgcv* package mean you don't need to choose knot locations and the complexity of the estimated function can be automatically selected as part of model fitting. The splines in *mgcv* would also make obtaining a separate smooth per `health` level easy to implement also.